# There is some errors when I use Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, capistrano, passenger

I had installed Ruby/Rails/Apache2/Passenger, I use Capitrano to deploy my Rails app.

But, When I deployed (no errers show), I visit my website, it noted some errors, and later, I get the error contents in `Apache2 log` via `passenger-config --detect-apache2` command.

```
$ passenger-config --detect-apache2
Looking for possible Apache installations...
 --> Looking for /home/cenx/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /home/cenx/.rbenv/libexec/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /home/cenx/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /home/cenx/.rbenv/shims/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /home/cenx/.rbenv/bin/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/local/sbin/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/local/bin/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/sbin/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/bin/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /sbin/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /bin/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/games/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/local/games/apxs2: not found
 --> Looking for /home/cenx/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /home/cenx/.rbenv/libexec/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /home/cenx/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /home/cenx/.rbenv/shims/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /home/cenx/.rbenv/bin/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/local/sbin/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/local/bin/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/sbin/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/bin/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /sbin/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /bin/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/games/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for /usr/local/games/apxs: not found
 --> Looking for : found

Analyzing ...
Detecting main Apache executable...
Detecting version...
 --> 2.4.7
Detecting control command...
Cannot find a usable Apache installation using .


----------------------------

Permission problems

Sorry, this program doesn't have enough permissions to autodetect all your
Apache installations, because it's running as the cenx user.
Please re-run this program with root privileges:

  export ORIG_PATH="$PATH"
  sudo -s -E
  export PATH="$ORIG_PATH"
  /home/cenx/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby /home/cenx/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.28/bin/passenger-config --detect-apache2
```

Hope you could help me, thanks!

Comment: Looks like Passenger can't find Apache. Check out https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4411223

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this program doesn't have enough permissions, so check the privileges.

> Please re-run this program with root privileges: